# Is it possible to call parameters from a string in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

For example:

```
x = "Hi my name is params[:name]"
```

or

```
x= "Hi my name is params[:name] and my favorite color is params[:color]"
```

I want to use one controller for a whole bunch of simple text request/responses but they might have unpredictable parameters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can interpolate variables in strings like this in ruby:

```ruby
x = "Hi my name is #{params[:name]} and my favorite color is #{params[:color]}"
```

Comment: So I could concievably pass this in to the controller from somewhere and as long as the parameters contained :name, and :color, it would work?

Comment: @Nickthemagicman: yes, it would. You may also consider to check if there are such parameters (in your controller method).